# Change Color of Shared Element Activity Transition "Blink"

Tags: android, android-activity, shared-element-transition

I have two activities in which I am animating a few elements between the two. There is a white "blink" to smooth the transition which would be fine but I'm using black backgrounds on both activities. I tried using `getWindow().setEnterTransition(null);` which worked but made the animation look crappy. Is there a way to change the color of the "blink" so that it's black?

[image: gif showing white "blink" during transition]